# I tried to use aeon . But my first transaction to wallet is in the blockchain but not in my balance

Tags: aeon

How to solve when my balance remains at zero after a transaction present in the block chain?

The options available are :

```
address              Show current wallet public address
  balance              Show current wallet balance
  bc_height            Show blockchain height
  help                 Show this help
  incoming_transfers   incoming_transfers [available|unavailable] - Show incoming transfers - all of them or filter them by availability
  payments             payments <payment_id_1> [<payment_id_2> ... <payment_id_N>] - Show payments <payment_id_1>, ... <payment_id_N>
  refresh              Resynchronize transactions and balance
  save                 Save wallet synchronized data
  save_bc              Save current blockchain data
  seed                 Get deterministic seed
  set_log              set_log <level> - Change current log detalization level, <level> is a number 0-4
  spendkey             Get spendkey
  start_mining         start_mining [<number_of_threads>] - Start mining in daemon
  stop_mining          Stop mining in daemon
  transfer             transfer <mixin_count> <addr_1> <amount_1> [<addr_2> <amount_2> ... <addr_N> <amount_N>] [payment_id] - Transfer <amount_1>,... <amount_N> to <address_1>,... <address_N>, respectively. <mixin_count> is the number of transactions yours is indistinguishable from (from 0 to maximum available)
  viewkey              Get viewkey
```

Answer (score 1):

The current aeon has a known bug which causes the wallet to skip over blocks without parsing them. This means any transaction in those blocks will be ignored.

To fix this, you need to set refresh-from-block-height to 0 (or a height prior to your wallet original creation) and run "rescan_bc". Type "set" to see the current value, and if it's 1 million or more, type "set 
refresh-from-block-height 0" then "rescan_bc". Your aeon should then appear after the rescan is complete (this does not download the blockchain again, it just parses the copy already on your machine).

Comment: the options above dont mention what you mentioned

Comment: The output you added to the first post looks an old version of the wallet. Update to current (0.12.2.1 or close). The wallet binary also got renamed from simplewallet to aeon-wallet-cli, make sure you use the right one. If you were just using an old version, that'd explain why it can't see incoming aeon, it's stuck on the fork a couple weeks back.

Comment: ok I had used this docker image https://github.com/ehehdada/aeoncash. I will update

Comment: Using random binaries from the web is a good way to lose your coins.

Comment: You are right , i created my docker image. Now it is synching .... a lot of data to download ... it is already to 2.5Gb. When wallet is synched it not possible to prune the blockchain to min level associated to wallet?

Comment: Aaon does have pruning, but I don't know how it works or how to enable it. I suggest you ask a separate question about Aeon pruning.